# Adjustable-width div sandwiched between two fixed-width divs

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a page that has three divs next to each other, each the same height.  Is is possible to have the first and third divs a fixed-width (say 175px), and have the middle div adjust it's width to the remaining space (and can be resized when the window width changes)?  I know it can be done with just two divs, but is this scenario with three feasible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you have markup similar to;

```
<div id="leftCol"></div>
<div id="rightCol"></div>
<div id="centerCol"></div>
```

You could do it like this with CSS;

```
#leftCol {float: left; width: 175px;}
#rightCol {float: right; width: 175px;}
#centerCol {overflow: hidden;}
```

See this on jsFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/meSHp/

Comment: Of course the solution was much simpler than I thought... which is a good thing!  Thanks!  Both you and Brian have pretty much identical answers but I'm accepting this one since it's more detailed on this page and may help others with the same question faster.  But thanks to both of you! :)

Comment: Thanks! When I discovered the overflow:hidden trick it totally changed my approach to CSS layouts. Of course, it can have negative side effects if you have something that you want to overflow the container, but for a lot of layouts that isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just float the two side column `div`s off to the left and right, give your center `div` margins equal to the width of the columns (to keep the width constrained if it ends up being taller than either side), and it should work like you say. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8eVz/.